# Does order of conditions in $and matter?

Tags: mongodb

Is there any difference between

```
{$and:[{a:1}, {b:2}]}
```

and

```
{$and:[{b:2}, {a:1}]}
```

Both a and b are indexed, but b is way more complicated field (its actually a list of dictionaries and there are $exist condition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a [difference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/):

> The **$and** operator uses short-circuit evaluation. If the first expression (e.g. **`<expression1>`**) evaluates to **false**, MongoDB will not evaluate the remaining expressions

If `{a: 1}` is faster to evaluate than `{b: 2}`, then you should put `a` first.